# How to debug registration failure of background task?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, lifecycle, overriding, background-task

I'm following the [MSDN guides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) on registering a background task (WindowsRunTime Component) in a Windows Phone 8.1 application. So far when debugging I trigger the `OnSuspending` event manually [via Visual Studio debug toolbar lifecycle option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx).

When I step through the code in the `OnSuspending` event the registration code executes as expected until I get to the line of code that calls `.Register()`

```
        BackgroundTaskRegistration parkingTimerTask = taskBuilder.Register();
```

After stepping into this line the debugger breaks out into the `App.g.i.cs` class with the following error description:

```
Parking Tag Picker WRT.exe!Parking_Tag_Picker_WRT.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__a(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 49  C#
```

**Question:**

Does anyone know how I can debug further why this call to register fails?
Or how can I output more info on the cause of the error to my output window?

I've re-checked my setup in regards to declaring the entry point in my manifest and all looks okay. Also there is a reference to the WindowsRunTime Component in my main app project.

[image]

**Code:**

**OnSuspending event in App.xaml.cs class:**

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application             state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();

        //Registration of ParkingTimer background task -->
        string myTaskName = "UpdateTimerTask";

        // check if task is already registered
        foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        if (cur.Value.Name == myTaskName)
        {
            //await(new MessageDialog("Task already registered")).ShowAsync();
            return;
        }

        // Windows Phone app must call this to use trigger types (see MSDN)
        await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        // register a new task
        BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder { Name = "Update Timer Task", TaskEntryPoint = "ParkingTimerTask.UpdateTimerTask" };
        taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(30, false));
        //Code fails at this call to register -->
        BackgroundTaskRegistration parkingTimerTask = taskBuilder.Register();

        //await(new MessageDialog("Task registered")).ShowAsync();

        // TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

**Skeleton code of the ParkingDurationTimerTask background task to be registered:**

```
namespace ParkingDurationTimerTask
{
    public sealed class UpdateTimerTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the background task reference to your main project? Is background task a WindowsRunTime Component?

Comment: Yes a reference has been added to the main project, also it is a WindowsRunTime Component to confirm. Not sure what the error means that gets thrown.

Comment: I just tried to do what you told in question. I dint get any exception. Can you post the link to your sample code where you get the exception

Comment: @LovetoCode sure my repo is here, I've linked to the app.xaml.cs code. It fails on the call to register in that method https://github.com/BrianJVarley/Parking-Tag-SMS-Client/blob/master/Parking%20Tag%20Picker%20WRT/App.xaml.cs

Comment: For the first time i got the exception. And on second run i created new Background Task and that got registered,then i tried your background task again it got registered. Weird..

Comment: Create the Task one more time(double check it is Windows Runtime component),add proper Entrypoint,add reference to main project

Comment: @LovetoCode could you detail the steps you took to resolve the error? You mean create a new Windows Runtime component and run through the registration steps again?

Comment: Yes exactly. did you try that?

Comment: Here is a link for working background task https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E4A5FCCA92E37830!487&authkey=!AGuXHd6iRY6xRiE&ithint=file%2czip